# Incrementing reference variable doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code is supposed to output `6`, but instead it outputs `5`. I can't figure out why. What's going on?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(T& y)
{
   y++;
}

int main()
{
   int x = 5;

   // Why won't this line work???/
   foo(x);

   std::cout << x;
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://ideone.com/1JhRm6)

Comment: [SPOILER WARNING!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=965ca9098aaef2bd5099a7c94ae60595-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Comment: isn't it UB due to sequencing?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Nope! Sequencing where?

Comment: @Lightness etc., y = y++ is UB no?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Yes, but I didn't write that in my code so I don't see the relevance.

Comment: Nice. I fell right into it.

Comment: @Liran: The function accepts a reference.

Comment: @gx_: There is nothing illegal about three consecutive `?`.

Comment: This blew my mind. Can you imagine receiving this sort of problem in a job interview or something?! Probability of looking stupid = 100%.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you [already knew the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10f4c328-8bff-4b46-84e1-69ec7004762f/view-source), why didn't you answer your own question?

Comment: @Dukeling: Shhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: This is basically a glorified bug report for the pretty printer syntax highlighter...? (Not sure whether to +1 or -1.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Haha yes that's true - hadn't thought of that

Comment: wow, I hitted submit answer ans saw other ten at the same time, people likes trigraphs!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Maybe this should be called a "smug report".

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah we could do that

Comment: @EdKing: If any interviewer ever asks me that question, I'll walk right out.

Comment: what a nice way to troll and receive awards!

Comment: @Dukeling Good spotted!

Comment: @DRC: I don't get any awards for it, unless you count the warm fuzzy feeling I receive when my good friends on Stack Overflow learn something new about C++ and have a little smile in the morning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a joke. See http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10f4c328-8bff-4b46-84e1-69ec7004762f/view-source

Comment: You need another `153` upvotes so you can reach [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736282/what-is-this-smiley-with-beard-expression) which I consider equivalent.

Comment: @johnchen902: It's not a joke if someone learns from it. In fact, it's no more a joke than a self-answered Q&A... that I _didn't_ post an A doesn't change that.

Comment: Three off-topic votes! Wow, you guys are _grumpy_.

Comment: The fact that this has been posted multiple times illustrates that there is little one would *learn* from it.

Comment: @devnull: On the contrary - the fact that this has been posted multiple times illustrates that there are plenty of people who have plenty to learn from it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True, but yet this particular question doesn't contribute much to a long-time learning effect, disguising the actual problem with a completely unrelated question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, the fact that this has been posted multiple times illustrates that it should be closed as duplicate. Unfortunately my duplicate vote was lumped in with the off-topic votes which made it practically invisible, and now the question has been reopened.

Comment: That happens when people carry their awful behaviour of multiple question marks over from their SO questions into their code!!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Compilers having been ignoring digraphs/trigraphs for a while now, at least gcc does.  I'm not sure what is there to learn here.

Comment: @devnull: I'm sorry you feel that way. 18 people saw fit to disagree with you enough to upvote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit People upvote pretty much anything.  Maybe if you ask why does `<:]{%>;` compile you'll gather enough upvotes.

Comment: @devnull: I hope your mood improves as the day progresses

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I heard somebody say `Sometimes, stackoverflow is the most depressing site on the internet.` a while back.  You seem to prove that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I give up.  I'm reminded of what I was once told: `Don't stoop down to anybody's level.  What if they start digging!`

Comment: Terrible duplicate. It's not even about the same trigraph or operator. It bears essentially no resemblance.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Trigraphs

You're using the good ol' trick of [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C).

```
// Why won't this line work???/
                            | |
                            \ /
                             |
                         ~trigraph~
```

The `??/` trigraph is in turn converted to `\` which basically concatenates the current line with the next line and thus your code becomes more or less like this:

```
// Why won't this line work? foo(x);
```

A fine trick indeed.

---

Quoting from the C++11 standard:

§2.2.2:

> Each instance of a **backslash character (\) immediately followed by a
>   new-line character** is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form
>   logical source lines. ...

§2.4.1:

```
Table 1 - Trigraph sequences
...
==========================
| Trigraph | Replacement |
==========================
|          ...           |
==========================
|   ??/    |      \      |
==========================
```

---

Fortunately, [GCC seems to detect this kind of trickery](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=965ca9098aaef2bd5099a7c94ae60595-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51), emitting a warning (just set `-Wall`):

```
main.cpp:13:32: warning: trigraph ??/ converted to \ [-Wtrigraphs]
    // Why won't this line work???/
 ^

main.cpp:13:4: warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]
    // Why won't this line work???/
    ^
```

---

<sub>Related references:</sub>

[meaning of `???-` in C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16662276/1619294)

[What is this smiley-with-beard expression: "<:]{%>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736282/1619294)

[What does the C ??!??! operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825055/what-does-the-c-operator-do)

And all other similar questions out there. ??)

<sub>PS: That's a smiley.</sub>

Comment: Oh! What an interesting and neat feature.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Interesting? Yes! Neat? No! Useful? Absolutely Not! When do they finally drop rubbish like that from the standard (together with the literal versions of the logical operators). Show me a single person that needs those nowadays for more than just "party knowledge" (or maybe entries to a hypothetical *IOC++CC*).

Comment: @ChristianRau that's some party...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you make out like you didn't know very convincingly.  I'd like to see the programmer that writes a comment `// Why won't this line work???/` before a line that they haven't tested yet. That must be a very pessimistic person...

Answer (score 8):

`??/` is a **Trigraph sequence** which is replaced with `\`.
For the compiler `\` means that immediate line that follows is a part of the current line. In this case the current line is a comment. The effective result is:

```
// Why won't this line work foo(x);
```

Comment: Oh! You're right! (BTW, 99.9k.. nice)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: We both know that you knew it already & you are just trolling ;-) Ah, I missed the moment though shows 100k already, not that I am complaining.

Comment: @AlokSave Congrats for your 100k RP

Answer (score 4):

It's **Trigraphs**. In c++11 specification

> ### 2.4 Trigraph sequences [lex.trigraph]
>
> <sup>1</sup> Before any other processing takes place, each occurrence of one of the following sequences of three characters
>   (*“trigraph sequences”*) is replaced by the single character indicated in Table 1.
>
> ```
>                      Table 1 — Trigraph sequences
>     Trigraph Replacement │ Trigraph Replacement │ Trigraph Replacement
>     ─────────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────────────
>        ??=      #        │    ??(      [        │    ??<      {
>        ??/      \        │    ??)      ]        │    ??>      }
>        ??’      ˆ        │    ??!      |        │    ??-      ~
> ```

Now replace `??/` with `\` and you'll find out.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Why won't this line work???/
   foo(x);
```

The trigraph `??/`turns to `\`, so the code will be translated to:

```
// Why won't this line work?\
   foo(x);
```

And string concatenation works.

When I tested it in g++, trigraph is turned off by default(generates a warning), it will output 6. If compiled using `g++ t.cpp -trigraphs`, will output 5.

Answer (score 2):

probably your comment is interpreted as a trigraph (not treegraph!) that "deletes" the function call.

http://ideone.com/sU4YGc works for me deleting that ??/ in the comment.

```
// Why won't this line work?
foo(x);
```

see also [Purpose of Trigraph sequences in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234582/purpose-of-trigraph-sequences-in-c)

Comment: Well. Is a tree a graph. Mmm. Some graphs can be a forest.... Mmm. I'm lost

Comment: ehehe, just mispelled tri for tree.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is your friend. This

```
   // Why won't this line work???/
   foo(x);
```

is a multiline comment, foo(x) is not executed!

The [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) "??/" is converted to "\" which indicates a linebreak into the comment.

Comment: What does the `/` do?

Comment: it converts to \ when it follows ??.

Trigraphs used in c and c++ can be found at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs

Comment: @StefanoFalasca you have a strange and roundabout way of arriving at the point. And your explanation is ... slightly misleading. '/' is not converted to '\\' when it follows anything. '??/' is _seen_ by the compiler as '\\' iff trigraphs are enabled. (Urffff. F*cken comment markdown)

Comment: actually, the trigraph ??/ doesn't even get to the compiler, the substitution is made by the preprocessor

Comment: @StefanoFalasca precisely what I said. The compiler _sees_ a '/'

Comment: @sehe: No, it sees a '\'.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not if run it through `cpp` first. [Note to self: can't win a pedantry war]